# error reading solve script template: error reading "/home/mike/.config/pwninit-template.py"

Tags: binary, elf, init, ctf, pwntools

While I was trying to run [pwninit](https://github.com/io12/pwninit) I was getting the following error

```
error: failed making template solve script: error reading solve script template:  
error reading "/home/mike/.config/pwninit-template.py": 
No such file or directory (os error 2)
```

What should I do?